# Lambda Expression simplification

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Is \xy.xy the same as \x.x?

I have to simplify an expression as much as possible and I don’t understand if these are equivalent

Comment: Does the word "eta" give you a hint?

Comment: Why do you think that the name matters and that one is simpler than the other?

Answer (score 0):

This question makes more sense when you think more generally about what you're doing by adding the parameter y and immediately applying it.

An equivalent question: given the function `Eta = λf . λy . f y`, is it true for all `f` that `Eta f == f`?

The answer depends ultimately on your definition of equality. If your definition of two functions `f, g` being "equal" is that, for all input expressions `x`, `f x == g x`, of course `Eta f == f`! The only operation to be done with a function is to apply it, so in a model of equality that only considers fully-applied values, a function that simply plumbs an argument along to its input is equal to the identity. The property that `Eta f == f` in some system is aptly named 'eta-equivalence', and some systems choose not to include it (notably, those that allow for syntactic manipulations).

Assuming eta-equivalence, yes, that is a legal simplification.